# error in enum with static initializer

Tags: java, enums

I'm currently working on a project (database implementation) involving an enum class called `ElementType` with a inner enum called `TypeType`. Inside `ElementType` there is a `HashMap<TypeType, ArrayList<ElementType>>` mapping all the `ElementType`'s to their corresponding `TypeType` values.

The values of `TypeType` are

```
[TEXT, NUMERIC_EXACT, NUMERIC_APPROX, OTHER]
```

The values of `ElementType` (and their corresponding `TypeType`) are

`[CHARACTER(TEXT),
 CHAR(TEXT),
DECIMAL(NUMBER_EXACT),
DEC(NUMBER_EXACT),
NUMERIC(NUMERIC_EXACT),
INTEGER(NUMERIC_EXACT),
INT(NUMERIC_EXACT),
SMALLINT(NUMERIC_EXACT),
FLAT(NUMERIC_APPROX),
REAL(NUMERIC_EXACT),
DOUBLE_PRECISION(NUMERIC_APPROX),
DOUBLE(NUMERIC_APPROX),
DATE(OTHER),
TIME(OTHER),
VARCHAR(OTHER),
LONG_VARCHAR(OTHER)]`

And in a `static {}` area, I have this code:

```
for(ElementType eType : values()) {
    TypeType t = eType.getTYPE();
    if(typeMapping.get(t) != null)
        typeMapping.get(t).add(eType);
    else
        typeMapping.put(t, new ArrayList<ElementType>() {add(eType);});
}
```

All of the `eType` mentions within the for loop are underlined red within Eclipse.

The first one gives the error `eType cannot be resolved`.

The second one gives `eType cannot be resolved to a variable`.

And the third one (inside the `ArrayList`) gives `Syntax error on token "eType", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token`.

The `getTYPE()` method is private and returns the TypeType for each ElementType.
The `typeMapping` is the HashMap mentioned above.

I don't know what is causing this or how to fix it, does anyone know how to fix this, or what I can do?

Comment: *"in a static {} area"* : do you mean in a static initialiser of the ElementType enum?

Comment: Next time: _Please_ do not write a poem for something where you can show us 5 line of codes. Code which we can immediately cut&paste into your IDEs to play with. See [SSCCE](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sscce.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
typeMapping.put(t, new ArrayList<ElementType>() {add(eType);});
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You try to create an inner, non-static class derived from `ArrayList` inside a static initializer block. If you replace that with a plain `new ArrayList` plus `alist.add(eType)` it will work.

**OR** you can use:

```
typeMapping.put(t, new ArrayList<ElementType>() {{add(eType);}});
```

Note 1: There must be *two* opening and closing braces. Hence the terminus ["double brace initialization"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization).

Note 2: For DBI you must make `eType` `final` in the loop.

Although I have to admit, that the error messages are *ahem* somewhat unclear.

Comment: It's also neccessary to convert `eType` declaration to final if second way is chosen.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, the first two errors i was getting i guess where just a glitch in eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that compiles and works at my maching `Java HotSpot 1.6.0_21':

```
import java.util.*;

public enum ElementType {

    CHARACTER(TypeType.TEXT), CHAR(TypeType.TEXT), DEC(TypeType.NUMERIC_EXACT);

    public static enum TypeType {
        TEXT, NUMERIC_EXACT;
    }

    private TypeType type;

    private ElementType(TypeType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private static Map<TypeType, List<ElementType>> typeMapping;

    static {
        typeMapping = new HashMap<TypeType, List<ElementType>>();
        for (ElementType eType : values()) {
            TypeType t = eType.type;
            if (!typeMapping.containsKey(t)) {
                typeMapping.put(t, new ArrayList<ElementType>());
            }
            typeMapping.get(t).add(eType);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(typeMapping);
    }
}
```

Does it work for you?